# Get the current view in a Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

**What I try to do**: I want to generate PDF of the current view
**More details:**: I got many clients and I want to create a button on each page so that I can generate PDF of each clients details.

Laravel package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

**What I have done up to now**:

1. I added DomPdf to my application
2. I created a *Route::resource('imprimer', 'PrintController');* route
3. I added a PrintController

```
class PrintController extends \BaseController{

    public function show(){
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('clients.show');
      return $pdf->stream();
}}
```

4. I included a link in my view (2 versions)

{{ HTML::linkAction('PrintController@show', 'PDF',array(), array('class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right mgright10')) }}

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('imprimer/' . $client->id) }}">Pdf2</a>
```

**My question**: How to pass to current view (ex: clients/1) to the controller so that the controller generates a PDF of the current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create a new way to call the "create PDF" function without having to add code to the PrintController.

**PrintController.php**

```
<?php
class PrintController extends \BaseController{

public function show( $id )
{
if( isset($id) )
{
    /** remove last 2 character */
    $class_name = substr( $id, 0, -2 );

    /** Stay only last character */
    $id = substr( $id, -1 );

    if( isset($class_name) )
    {
        $with_method = 'with'.ucfirst( $class_name ); // withClient
        $find_method = ucfirst( $class_name ); // Client
        $html = View::make( $class_name .'s.show' )->$with_method( $find_method::find($id) );    
    }
    else
    {
        $html = 'Data Not Found!';
    }

    $pdf = App::make( 'dompdf' );
        $pdf->loadHTML( $html );
        return $pdf->stream(); 
}
}
}
```

**View** (Only the client and $client to remplace)

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('imprimer/'.'client='. $client->id) }}" target="_blank">
  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right mgright10">PDF2</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a variable that contains the current view name, since there's no built in method for that. We can use `View::composer` which is basically a callback for when a view gets rendered.

```
View::composer('*', function($view){
    View::share('view_name', $view->getName());
});
```

If it only affects certain views you could also restrict it by changing `*` to another mask.

So now you can do:

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('PrintController@show', 'PDF', array($view_name), array('class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right mgright10')) }}
```

And receive it in your controller:

```
public function show($viewName){
   //...
}
```

Comment: I added The View:composer code block in filters.php. I got an Undefined variable: viewName (View: ...app\views\clients\show.blade.php) error

Comment: Oh my bad. one time i wrote `view_name` and the other `$viewName`... answer is updated

Comment: I now get Undefined variable: client (View: ...\app\views\clients\show.blade.php) I'll try to see why, but If you know, just tell me ;)

Comment: Hmm no idea to be honest

Answer (score 1):

I found how (I was close to it). Here is how I did for reference:

**PrintController.php**

```
class PrintController extends \BaseController{
public function show($id)
{
    $client_id = Client::find( $id );
    $html = View::make( 'clients.show' )->withClient( $client_id );
    $pdf = App::make( 'dompdf' );
    $pdf->loadHTML( $html );
    return $pdf->stream();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('imprimer/'.$client->id) }}">
  <button>PDF</button>
</a>
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::resource('imprimer', 'PrintController');
```

Comment: But now you have to make a new controller function every time you want to print a page with a different view. Didn't you get my answer to work?

Comment: Yes I know I actually try to merge my answer and your answer.

Comment: So whats the problem with my solution? Still the `$client` variable?

Comment: Yes it's about the $client variable.

Comment: Do you normally pass this variable in when creating the view in the controller?